# How to disable dot replacement in bash?

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to run MySQL query from bash script to create new user:

```
mysql -u root -p$dbpass -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON appdb_${BUILD}.* TO appuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass'"
```

Where $BUILD variable is set to a number, for example 15, so final query should look like this:

```
mysql -u root -p$dbpass -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON appdb_15.* TO appuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass'"
```

But... in directory where script is and is run there is a tar archive with same name as database, so query becomes like this:

```
mysql -u root -p$dbpass -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON appdb_15.tar.gz TO appuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass'"
```

I guess this happens because there is a match, but changing file name is not an option. Moving script to other directory is not allowed too.

I tried to escape dot with backslashes (`appdb_${BUILD}\.*`) - nothing changed.

How I can fix this?

Comment: It's not the dot you need to escape, it's the asterisk. Why did you think it's the dot? This is no regex.

Comment: Also, asterisk isn't normally expanded in double quotes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well, dont know why dot i thought about dot, not asterisk, that was just first thing which came to my mind. To much regex I guess. Anyway, now after escaping asterisk, now mysql complains that he doesnt understand what `\*` is...

Comment: To be sure, this is *not* a `bash` issue. `mysql` is receiving the quoted string as it should be, as evidenced by the fact that `mysql` is complaining about `\*`.

Comment: @chepner: yes, but how to explain glob expansion then?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approach and it is working in my case. See below. Can you tell us what is the error that you are getting so that we can help you?

```
[root@cloud mysql]# ls
appdb_15.tar.gz  test.sh

[root@cloud mysql]# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

BUILD=15
# First Method
mysql -u root -ptest -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON appdb_${BUILD}.* TO appuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';"

# Second Method
mysql -u root -ptest <<EOF
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON appdb_${BUILD}.* TO appuser1@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';
select user, host from mysql.user where user like 'appuser%';
EOF

[root@cloud mysql]# ./test.sh
user    host
appuser localhost
appuser1        localhost
```

**EDIT 1:**
 I forgot to mention that this is definitely not a bash issue.

**EDIT 2**: Changed the build variable to 15 from 5.

Comment: Your test env is flawed. `appdb_15.tar.gz`, but `$BUILD` is `5`. If it were bash glob expansion, it wouldn't trigger here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Even if it was 15 it will not trigger bash glob expansion. I tried with 15 as well and I was able to create the user

Comment: Well, must be that snippets in the question don't accurately represent what's happening, then.